# How to use the !str_detect() function to exclude observations from a variable

Tags: r

I am working with this dataframe https://www.data.gouv.fr/s/resources/election-presidentielle-des-23-avril-et-7-mai-2017-resultats-definitifs-du-1er-tour-par-communes/20170427-100544/Presidentielle_2017_Resultats_Communes_Tour_1_c.xls

I imported it like so :

```
elections_2017 <- read_excel("~/Downloads/Presidentielle_2017_Resultats_Communes_Tour_1_c.xls",skip =3, guess_max = 35723,.name_repair = janitor::make_clean_names )
```

I renamed the variable `code_du_departement` into `code_departement`  into a copy of the dataset `elections_2017` called `elections_2017_clean` like so :

```
elections_2017_clean <- elections_2017
names(elections_2017_clean)[which(names(elections_2017_clean)=="code_du_departement")] <- "code_departement"
```

Now I am only interested in analysing mainland French departments, so I want to want get rid of departments whose code starts with “Z” as well as Corsica (“2A” and “2B”).

I know I have to use the `str_detect()` function from the `stringr` package in my `filter()` function. Since I want to exclude departments codes containing a “Z” I will also need to use `!str_detect()`, the `!` implying that I want to exclude whatever comes after it. And also want to exclude Corsica departments “2A” and “2B”.

I should create a new object `elections_2017_long_metrop` to do this but I don't know how to put into the function and neither how to tabulate the variable `code_departement` to verify if it was done properly.

Answer (score 1):

Raed's answer above will work (and is probably more elegant), but if you want to use `str_detect()`, then try this:

```
elections_2017_long_metro <- elections_2017_clean %>%
  filter(!str_detect("Z", code_departement),
         !str_detect("2A", code_departement),
         !str_detect("2B", code_departement))
```

Comment: Excellent use of the tidyverse package.  As a note, you could use OR inside the first str_detect to reduce the length and runtime of your code like this:

!str_detect("Z|2A|2B", code_departement)

Answer (score 0):

```
elections_2017_clean <- tibble(code_departement = letters,
               var1 =rnorm(26,0,1),
               var2 =rnorm(26,0,1))


elections_2017_long_metrop <- elections_2017_clean %>% 
  filter(!grepl("z|a|b", code_departement))
```

that is a solution for artificial data, for your problem you can replace the string *grepl* argument with "Z|2a|2b"

Comment: Thank you ! and do you know what "tabulate" means because I have to tabulate the variable "code_departement" to make sure it was done properly but I don't really know what that means

Answer (score 0):

Raed Hamed above added a perfectly acceptable solution using grepl.  I don't like grepl because it is **much** slower on very large datasets.

Before I answer your exact question, I want to try to address all the future questions you could have about using the `stringr` package and recommend you go to this page https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/ and read the **Work with Strings Cheatsheet**.  It's only 2 pages, and I use it almost every time I work with `stringr` because it succintly details the rules needed for proper implementation of REGEX.

As for your particular situation, I would it something like this:

```
elections_2017_long_metrop <- elections_2017_clean[!str_detect(elections_2017_clean$code_departement,"Z|2A|2B"),]
```

*Edit: While I was typing this, semaphorism posted a reply that makes very good use of the tidyverse library.  Their code is much easier to read, understand, and implement than what I've given you here, but the filter function is around an order of magnitude slower than using bracket notation the way I just did which probably isn't relevant for your use case but is worth remembering if you get deeper into the weeds.*

Comment: Thank you so much ! and do you know what "tabulate" means because I have to tabulate the variable "code_departement" to make sure it was done properly but I don't really know what that means –

Comment: @MarieSolone So, tabulating something is to make it into a table.  If you're doing this in RStudio, you should be able to just look at the environment pane and click on the dataframe you've created to look through the code_departement column and make sure you don't see any of the departments you're trying to get rid of.  If it's for an assignment, you might want to talk to whomever assigned it and get some clarity on what format they want it back in.

Comment: Thank you @SirTain ! That is what I had in mind, just using the View() function to take a look at the results but you are right I will ask for more details again thank you !